# full calendar + jquery ui dialogue

Tags: php, javascript, jquery-ui

I am using a fullcalendar:-
http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/

and I am using jquery .post to get a parameter back to the same page to generate some result, and this is working well.

At the same time, I wish to use jquery ui dialogue to hold the displayed contents. While pasting the sample codes from official site, the example works. However, when combining the .post output with dialogue, it was not successful.

I would like to seek help in combining the below 2 sets of scripts:-

//for generating .post output (working!)

```
<script>
function event_details(thevalue){
$.post('module/calendar/event_details.php',{
eid:thevalue},

function(output){
    $('#theeventmsg').html(output);
});
}
</script>
<div id='theeventmsg'></div>
```

//jquery ui dialogue (working!)

```
<script>
// increase the default animation speed to exaggerate the effect
$.fx.speeds._default = 1000;
$(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        show: "blind",
        hide: "explode"
    });

    $( "#opener" ).click(function() {
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
        return false;
    });
});
</script>



<div class="demo">
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
    <p>This is an animated dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>
<button id="opener">Open Dialog</button>
</div><!-- End demo -->
```

Can help??? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @Speransky Danil, I would like to use dialogue to contain the html output from .post and pop up...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<script>
  $.fx.speeds._default = 1000;

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({ autoOpen: false });

    $('#button').click(function () {
      var data = { ... };

      $.post('module/calendar/event_details.php', data, function (output) {
        $('#dialog p').html(output);
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog("open");
      });
    });
  });
</script>    

<div id="dialog">
  <p>content</p>
</div>

<button id="button">button</button>
```

Or:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    function eventdetail(thevalue) {
      $.post('event_details.php', { eid: thevalue }, function (output) {
        $('#dialog p').html(output);
        $("#dialog").dialog({ autoOpen: true });
      });
    }

    $('#button').click(function () { eventdetail('value'); });
  });  
</script>

<div id="dialog">
  <p>content</p>
</div>

<button id="button">button</button>
```

Comment: actually, my friend can call a dialogue box up using:- 
<script>
function eventdetail(thevalue){

$.post('event_details.php',{eid:thevalue},
function(output){
$('#theeventmsg').html(output);
$("#theeventmsg").dialog({width:350,height:300});
});
}

</script>

but I cannot!!!